# How can I copy a variable in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

In numpy I can create a copy of the variable with [numpy.copy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html). Is there a similar method, that I can use to create a copy of a Tensor in TensorFlow?

Answer (score 38):

You asked how to copy a variable in the title, but how to copy a tensor in the question.  Let's look at the different possible answers.

(1)  You want to create a *tensor* that has the same value that is currently stored in a *variable* that we'll call `var`.

```py
tensor = tf.identity(var)
```

But remember, 'tensor' is a graph node that will have that value when evaluated, and any time you evaluate it, it will grab the *current* value of `var`.  You can play around with [control flow ops such as `with_dependencies()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/control_flow_ops#Control_Flow_Operations) to see the ordering of updates to the variable and the timing of the identity.

(2)  You want to create another variable and set its value to the value currently stored in a variable:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
var = tf.Variable(0.9)
var2 = tf.Variable(0.0)
copy_first_variable = var2.assign(var)
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(init)

print sess.run(var2)
sess.run(copy_first_variable)
print sess.run(var2)
```

(3)  You want to define a variable and set its starting value to the same thing you already initialized a variable to (this is what nivwu.. above answered):

```py
var2 = tf.Variable(var.initialized_value())
```

`var2` will get initialized when you call `tf.initialize_all_variables`.  You can't use this to copy var after you've already initialized the graph and started running things.

Comment: `with_dependencies()` changed, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37980078/tensorflow-has-no-attribute-with-dependencies

Comment: @dga regarding your point (1), would it not be better to just create a constant tensor somehow along the lines of tensor = tf.constant(var) such that the copy won't be dependent on var?

Answer (score 10):

You can do this in a couple of ways.

- this will create you a copy: `v2 = tf.Variable(v1)`
- you can also use [identity op](http://tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#identity): `v2 = tf.identity(v1)` (which I think is a proper way of doing it.

Here is a code example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

v1 = tf.Variable([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
v_copy1 = tf.Variable(v1)
v_copy2 = tf.identity(v1)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
a, b = sess.run([v_copy1, v_copy2])
sess.close()

print a
print b
```

Both of them would print the same tensors.

Comment: It is not specified if we want shallow or deep copy. I think it's safer to assume that it's about deep copy. in that case tf.Variable(source_variable.initialized_value())

Comment: @nivwusquorum can you show me the example when the identity will fail?

Comment: deepq learning requires a deep copy of q network in place of target network for example..

Comment: @niwu - there's no "shallow" or "deep" copy of a tensorflow variable.  Variables hold tensors, and tensors don't have pointers.  But please see my answer for why just doing v_copy1 = tf.Variable(v1) may not be correct either -- you're right that it may try to grab the value of v1 before v1 has been initialized, whereas using .initialized_value() will add a control dependency so that v1 gets initialized before the grab.  But the terms "shallow" and "deep" copy have a specific technical meaning that doesn't apply here.

Comment: This approach is not working for me for some reasons. I restore model and a variable which is a `tf.Variable()`. However, when I create another variable using `tf.identity()` and run it in a session, it prints out different values.

Answer (score 6):

This performs a deep copy

```
copied_variable = tf.Variable(source_variable.initialized_value())
```

It also handles intialization properly, i.e.

```
tf.intialize_all_variables()
```

will properly initialize source_variable first and then copy that value to copied_variable

Answer (score 1):

In TF2 :
`tf.identity()` will do the good deed for you. Recently I encountered some problems using the function in google colab. In case that's why you're here, this will be helping you.

> ***Error** : Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 in order to run Identity: No unary variant device copy function found for direction: 1 and Variant type_index: tensorflow::data::(anonymous namespace)::DatasetVariantWrapper [Op:Identity]*

```
#Erroneous code
tensor1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([[[1], [2]], [[3], [4]]])
tensor2 = tf.identity(tensor1)
```

```
#Correction
tensor1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([[[1], [2]], [[3], [4]]])
with tf.device('CPU'): tensor2 = tf.identity(tensor1)
```