# what does `control_flow_ops.with_dependencies` mean for tensoflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am reading the code of tensorflow model:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/train_image_classifier.py

I am very confused with this code part:

```
train_tensor = control_flow_ops.with_dependencies([update_op], total_loss,
                                                  name='train_op')
```

What does control_flow_ops.with_dependencies mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function has two arguments `control_flow_ops.with_dependencies(dependencies, output_tensor)`. The second argument `output_tensor`, which in your case is `total_loss` is evaluated only *after* all operations in `dependencies` are evaluated. As the name implies, `output_tensor` depends on the dependencies for proper evaluation. This function enforces this behaviour.

Dependencies is an iterable of operations, in your case a single `update_op` in a list.

Comment: Thanks @vega. Another question: Are `train_tensor ` and `total_loss` the same tensor?

Comment: Yup, the function specifies: "Produces the content of `output_tensor` only after `dependencies` ... Returns same as `output_tensor`."

Answer (score 2):

Firstly `with_dependencies` is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52733788/1090562), use `tf.control_dependencies` instead.

As for what it does, it produces the output of some value only after the dependencies are calculated. I usually use it to assert some values. For example:

```
assert_op = tf.Assert(tf.less_equal(tf.reduce_max(x), 1.), [x]) # max(x) <= 1
with tf.control_dependencies([assert_op]):
    x= tf.identity(x)
```